# Angularjs form submission and navigation to other page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have a index page where there is a form with text field and a search button. When the user clicks search button, the form needs to take the value of the text field and navigate to search page using get method.So that the search content will be displayed in the url of the search page.
I need to do it using angularjs.

Please suggest me a way or give me an overall idea how it works.

Answer (score 2):

If the site you are using is not blocking cross domain request then you could do something like this(Live Preview http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/WraEOY):

HTML:

```
    <h1>Submit To Search Engine On Key Up</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form>
    Search:
    <input type="text" ng-model="keyword" ng-keyup="search()">
  </form>

  <div ng-bind="results"></div>

</div>
```

Angular/JavaScript

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  //you can change the value of this to someting else like
  //search.html?search=  if you want
  var url = "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=";

$scope.search = function(){
  $http.get(url + $scope.keyword)
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.results = response;
    }, function(response) {
      $scope.results = "Something went wrong";
    });


};

});
```

or if you want it to sumbit your get variable to another page without using the $http function as Kaveh suggested you can change your Controller to the following code:

HTML:

```
    <h1>Submit input as http variable(GET) to another page</h1>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form>
    Search:
    <input type="text" ng-model="keyword">
    <input type= "button" value ="search" ng-click="search();">
  </form>

  <div ng-bind="results"></div>

</div>
```

Angular/JavaScript

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  //you can change the value of this to someting else like
  //search.html?search=  if you want
  var url = "search.html?search=";

$scope.search = function(){


   //navigate to another page using keyword model variable
   window.location = url + $scope.keyword;


};

});
```

Comment: Why don't just change window location? `window.location="https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=active&q=" + $scope.keyword`

Comment: Thank you so much. But i wanted to navigate to other page called "search.html" with the value of the text field. How am i supposed to do that?

Comment: Check out the alternate solution in my answer and it should be able to help with what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `ui-router` module and using `ui-sref` to navigate to search page passing the search Field Keyword.

Here is the API Reference [UI-Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)

```
<a ui-sref="pages.search({ search: keyword })" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
```